# Як відрізнити відмінювані слова іншомовного походження від невідмінюваних?

Tags: правопис, запозичені-слова, відмінювання

> Деякі іменники іншомовного походження не відмінюються, а саме:
>   іменники -а з попереднім голосним: амплуа, боа, Жоффруа; на -е: кафе,
>   кашне, турне; Беранже, Гейне, Гете, Данте; на -є: ательє, Барб’є,
>   Готьє, Лавуазьє; на -і: колібрі, поні, таксі; Гальвані, Голсуорсі,
>   Россіні, Фірдоусі, Шеллі; на -ї: Віньї, Шантійї; на -о: бюро, депо,
>   кіно, манто, метро, радіо; Арно, Буало, Віардо, Гюго, Дідро,
>   Лонгфелло, Тассо (але пальто відмінюється); на -йо: імброльйо,
>   Пількомайо; на -у: какаду, рагу, Шоу; на -ю: інтерв’ю, меню, Сю;
>   жіночі імена на приголосний, а також жіночі прізвища на -ін, -ов:
>   Аліс, Долорес, Зейнаб; (Ельза) Вірхов, (Джеральдіна) Чаплін.

Як визначити, які слова відмінювати, а які - ні?

> Авокадо
>   невідм., с. 1) Вічнозелене дерево з сімейства лаврових з їстівними
>   плодами. 2) Плід цього дерева.
>
> АВОКАДО — неизм.; ср. [португ. abacate из ацтек.]. Вечнозелёное дерево
>   из семейства лавровых со съедобными плодами (произрастает в тропиках и
>   субтропиках). // Плод этого дерева. * * * АВОКАДО АВОКАДО, древесное
>   растение рода персея, плодовая культура.… … Энциклопедический словарь
>
> До незмінюваних іменників в українській мові належать:
>   - слова іншомовного походження (таксі, колібрі, меню, бра);

буду вдячна за будь-яку допомогу!

Comment: Цитуӱ пані: _Деякі іменники іншомовного походження не відмінюються, а саме … на **‑о**_; _Авокадо **невідм.**…_  Чи ӓ чогось не зрозумів.

Comment: "авокадо", як приклад.... А чи є правило, щоб не перевіряти кожного разу в словнику?

Comment: @Orti, я взяв на себе сміливість змінити загаловок Вашого запитання, бо, мені здається, так воно краще відбиває суть запитання. (Якщо ж я помилився й новий заголовок не відповідає Вашим намірам — сміливо редагуйте його назад або на який Ви вважаєте доречним.)

Answer (score -4):

Згідно з "[§ 111. ВІДМІНЮВАННЯ СЛІВ ИНШОМОВНОГО ПОХОДЖЕННЯ](https://r2u.org.ua/pravopys/pravXXI/111.html)" іменники іншомовного походження не відмінюються якщо:

> 6. Не відмінюємо іменники иншомовного походження з кінцевими:
>
> а (у тих випадках, коли перед а виступає инший голосний, коли слово
>   односкладове, у власних і непослідовно в загальних назвах з
>   наголошеним а, а також непослідовно у власних назвах з ненаголошеним
>   а: амплуа́, боа́, мас-ме́дія, Брази́лія (столиця Бразилії),
>   Нікара́гуа; бра, па; антраша́, бакара́, Доза́, Дюма́, Сая́т-Нова́;
>   Вітто́ріо де Си́ка (але, наприклад, прізвища Казано́ва, Куроса́ва
>   відмінюємо);
>
> е: кафе́, кашне́, турне́, Туапсе́, Беранже́, Ґе́те;
>
> є: ательє́, конферансьє́, Барб’є́, Ґотьє́, Лавуазьє́;
>
> и (крім випадків, коли ця буква означає форму множини іменників:
>   Єсентуки́ і т. ин.): Алмати́, Аман-гельди́, Мари́;
>
> і: колі́брі, по́ні, таксі́, цуна́мі, Гаї́ті, Дебюссі́, Ше́ллі;
>
> ї: Віньї́, Луї́;
>
> о (коли перед ним стоїть инший голосний): ра́діо, Онта́ріо, Бази́ліо,
>   Ма́ріо, але пальто́ — пальта́, пальто́м, (у) пальті́; так само б’юро́,
>   депо́, кіно́, метро́, ситро́;
>
> у: какаду́, у́рду, шо́у, Баку́, Папандре́у, Попе́ску;
>
> ю: інтерв’ю́, меню́, К’юсю́, Сю;
>
> я (в позиції під наголосом або в односкладових словах): Золя́.
>
> До невідмінюваних належать також жіночі імена, що закінчуються на
>   твердий приголосний звук, крім губних: Алі́с, Беатри́с, Гу́друн,
>   Доло́рес, Еди́т, Елізабе́т, Енн, Есте́р, І́нґрид, Карме́н (але Ете́ль
>   — Ете́лі, Ете́ллю; Ізабе́ль — Ізабе́лі, Ізабе́ллю; Зейна́б — Зейна́бі,
>   Зейна́б’ю; Руф — Ру́фі, Ру́ф’ю), а також слова мада́м, міс, мі́сис,
>   фре́йлейн та ин. (але мадемуазе́ль — мадемуазе́лі і т. д.).
>
> Прізвища з кінцевим приголосним, якщо вони стосуються жінок, не
>   відмінюємо, як і власне українські: Елеоно́ра Ру́звельт — Елеоно́ри
>   Ру́звельт, Елеоно́рі Ру́звельт, Елеоно́рою Ру́звельт.
>
> До невідмінюваних належать також російські прізвища, що є застиглими
>   формами родового відмінка однини і множини: Жарки́х, Жива́го,
>   Дурново́, По́льських.

Також у параграфі міститься інформація про ті іменники, які відмінюються.

Comment: Це проєкт 99, очевидно, щось [особливо] тут не збігає ся з чинним правописом.

Comment: Анатолій, з одного боку — я згоден з follower, що те, що Ви цитуєте — це фрагменти з **відхиленого** [проекту правопису 1999 року](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Проект_правопису_1999_року), і деякі настанови цього правопису суперечать чинному правопису (наприклад, _минулої осени_ vs _минулої осені_, _пів години_ vs _півгодини_ тощо). З іншого боку, курс цього проекту-99 не на 100% відрізняється від курсу чинного, і якісь аспекти цілком можуть бути в ньому просто формально описані іншими словами, але за суттю не суперечити ***<продовжу…>***

Comment: ***<…продовжую>*** чиному правопису (і те, які іншомовні слова відмінюються, а які ні, теоретично може бути однією з таких речей) — й оскільки чинний проєкт-99 просто ретельніше висловлює критерії, за якими можна відрізнити відмінювані й невідмінювані слова іншомовного походження, то мені здається, інформація з нього теж може бути корисною навіть тому читачу, що послуговується чинним правописом — просто для орієнтування (не кажучи вже про те, що вона може бути корисною для прихильників альтернативного правопису). Тому, по-моєму, Ваша відповідь може ***<продовжу…>***

Comment: ***<…продовжую>*** бути **дуже корисною**, якщо Ви просто додасте попередження для користувача, мовляв, _«це інформація з альтернативного (не ухваленого) проекту правопису, не сприймайте її як істину в останній інстанції (якщо ви слідуєте чинному правопису, звісно), але в чомусь вона може допомогти»_. (Зовсім ідеально було б зацитувати поряд відповідні фрагменти чинного правопису й, можливо, зробити порівняння — але то вже може бути забагато роботи.)

Comment: Див. також [фрагмент сторінки «Про альтернативні правописи і нестандартні діалекти» на ме́та-сайті](//ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/157) — якщо коротко, то ми не проти надання/поширення інформації стосовно альтернативних правописів, але читач має чітко бачити межу, де закінчується опис чинної норми й починається інформація про альтернативні погляди.

Comment: **TLDR**: Особисто я поставив Вам мінус не через те, що Ви «цитуєте відхилений проект правопису», а через те, що Ви «цитуєте відхилений проект правопису і _не зазначили це_». Зазначите — особисто я зміню на плюс. (Бо й інформація з відхиленого проекту може бути корисною.)